# Office365 returns same recordd ID for Two different Contacts?

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

Recently we have developed integration with Office365 to sync Contacts and Calendar events from Office365 and every thing seems to be working as expected. But today I faced one different issue where I followed this test case.

I created couple of contacts in Office365 and synced back to our application. Later imported around 500 contacts in Office365 and synced again. After the sync I noticed that 4 contacts were updated even though there was no update (which have been created). Because of this update my existing 4 contacts were overwritten.

I went through the logs and noticed that office365 record IDs of 4 records that were synced earlier had the same record IDs for the 4 contacts that were created after the import in office365.

My question is even though **ID** is unique identifier for office365 record (according to their [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RESTAPIResourcesContact)) why two contacts has same record ID?

Is there any other unique identifier for Office365 contacts record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Id` is case-sensitive. So if you're comparing, you need to make sure that you're taking that into account.

Comment: Thank you Jason, you were right the ID is case sensitive. Because mysql collate was set to insensitive this issue was happening.